QuickBooks SDK freezing with error: Failed to read PIC feature status from DCE, fall back to default value in Event Viewer
I have a C# .net app that is integrating with Quickbooks via the QBSDK160_x64 library. It has recently started freezing when calling the  qbSsnMgr.BeginSession()  and qbSsnMgr.CloseConnection() methods. I find the following error event in Windows Event Viewer:
- <System>
  <Provider Name="QuickBooks" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">4</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>2</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-07-25T20:28:44.650737900Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>133821</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>JJS-QB.universal.local</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>Intuit QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions: Manufacturing and Wholesale 24.0</Data> 
  <Data>Failed to read PIC feature status from DCE, fall back to default value</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>```

